# How to disable DNS host name lookups?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am using JDBC to connect MySQL as online, when I tried to connect or fetch data from database or insert data it takes at least 15 seconds or more.

I searched the problem as I can, and I got a solution that says you have to disable DNS lookup, then I tried to search again how to disable it, but I didn't get clear steps that I can understand.

So that I need some help that shows me how to disable the DNS lookup step by step. I am using MySQL as the database in Siteground host.

Comment: Please do **not** expose a MySQL database publicly on the Internet, as it is not designed for that and will get hacked. Please do **not** use JDBC on Android, as JDBC is designed for a reliable network connection, and mobile data connections are not reliable.

Comment: So what do you suggest me to use

Comment: Have your mobile app talk to a Web service, which in turn talks to your database.

Comment: No, my app talks directly to the database;

Comment: Please do not do that.

Comment: So, How do i talk to the database? is there any other solution that you will suggest me?

Comment: [As I wrote previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592260/how-to-disable-dns-host-name-lookups?noredirect=1#comment86193056_49592260), have your mobile app talk to a Web service, which in turn talks to your database.

Comment: which web server you recommend?